# SLD filter (PropertyIsEqualTo)

Tags: sld

Is an SLD filter like this valid?

```
<ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        <ogc:PropertyName>aaaaaa</ogc:PropertyName>
        <ogc:PropertyName>bbbbb</ogc:PropertyName>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
</ogc:Filter>
```

or is a Literal always required?

Comment: You mean can you specify a filter that is true if two properties have the same value?

Answer (score 2):

I think Literal is always required with that operator. Morever this snippet code is not valid because seems OR or AND condition: take a look [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.6.x/en/user/styling/sld-reference/filters.html#logical-operators).
An example of your code could be:

```
<ogc:Or>
   <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
   <ogc:PropertyName>aaaaaa</ogc:PropertyName>
   <ogc:Literal>cccccc</ogc:Literal>
   </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
   <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
   <ogc:PropertyName>bbbbb</ogc:PropertyName>
   <ogc:Literal>ddddddd</ogc:Literal>
   </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
   </ogc:Filter>
 </ogc:Or>
```